# manipulating commit history while avoiding merge conflicts between branches

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

Our team has started to use git for the first time. We have 3 branches: master, a and b. Master has five commits (commit1 to commit5), while branches a and b also contains all five commits plus some new commits of their own. a and b would be merged to master in the future.

Recently, I discovered that commits 2 and 3 does not belong in master. It should belong in a. Master should only have commits 1, 4 and 5. Commits 2 and 3 will be merged later. This is when we haven't yet created separate branches. This is a problem because a and b are branched out of master, thus having the same first 5 commits.

Is there a way to remove commits 2 and 3 out of master and b while avoiding merge conflicts later when we merge a into master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is generally "no".  However, since there are so relatively few commits, and your team is probably small enough, there is one way to deal with this fairly, cleanly and several more that are a bit messier but might suffice.  (Also, a brief side note: there are faster ways to do almost everything I describe below, using the power tools versions of the individual, one-commit-at-a-time methods.  I'm going to leave them out for space reasons.)

#### The TL;DR summary

I would probably go for the history rewrite, given that the repository is so small and your team is probably capable of dealing with it.  (This is especially true if everyone can work together for a few hours or so on it.)  In a bigger project I might go for the last (hybrid) alternative I show below—or, in many cases, just ignore the problem since the commits I label `B` and `C` are probably not causing too much distress.  But all of these are value [judgments](http://grammarist.com/spelling/judgment-judgement/) that don't necessarily have a "correct" answer.

#### The long part

The main trick is to start by drawing the commits.  Remember that in Git, a commit is identified by its big ugly hash ID, and each commit records the hash ID of its parent commit.  This means that commits always "point backwards", and in fact Git always works backwards.  Each commit also contains a complete snapshot of the entire source: whenever you view a commit as a *change*, you are doing this by having Git look backwards from that commit, to its parent, and then compare the two snapshots.

The hash ID of each commit depends very strongly (via cryptographic hash) on everything about the commit: the author and committer name and email addresses and time stamps, the source snapshot, the commit message, and the parent commit hash ID as well.  So if you try to change *anything* about a commit, you get a new, different hash ID.

Rather than writing out big ugly hash IDs, though, I'll just use a single uppercase letter for each commit (and run out after just 26 commits...).  You have this, more or less (I'm just guessing two commits for each of the two branches):

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G   <-- branch-a
```

(Note that branch names like `master` act as moveable pointers, pointing to the *last* commit on the branch.  Adding new commits to a branch works by making the new commit point back to the current tip, then moving the branch name to point to the new commit.  Git now finds all the commits that used to be on the branch because it starts from the new commit and works backwards, and the first step back takes it to the old tip.)

#### Method one: the massive history rewrite (not that massive)

What you'd *like* to have, but can't quite have, is this:

```
        H--I   <-- branch-b
       /
A--D--E   <-- master
       \
        B--C--F--G   <-- branch-a
```

This diagram can't be achieved because the hash ID for `D` represents a commit whose parent is `A` and whose source snapshot is that for what's in `D` right now, which is similar to the snapshot in `C`.

What we *can* do is to make a commit, let's call it `D'`, that has `A` as its parent, and takes the change-from-`C`-to-`D` and applies that change to the snapshot in `A`.  We get this by using `git checkout` to check out commit `A` directly (as a "detached HEAD"), then making a branch name `new-master` point to it, using:

```
$ git checkout <hash of A>
$ git checkout -b new-master
```

or in one step using:

```
$ git checkout -b new-master <hash of A>
```

giving:

```
A   <-- new-master (HEAD)
 \
  B         H--I   <-- branch-b
   \       /
    C--D--E   <-- master
           \
            F--G   <-- branch-a
```

Now that we have this new named branch, we can use `git cherry-pick` to *copy* commit `D`:

```
$ git cherry-pick <hash of D>
```

Cherry-pick will compare `D` vs its parent `C`, and use the resulting changes to apply the changes to where we are now (`HEAD = new-master`) and make a new commit `D'`:

```
A--D'   <-- new-master (HEAD)
 \
  B         H--I   <-- branch-b
   \       /
    C--D--E   <-- master
           \
            F--G   <-- branch-a
```

Now that we have `D'` we can cherry-pick `E` as well:

```
A--D'-E'   <-- new-master (HEAD)
 \
  B         H--I   <-- branch-b
   \       /
    C--D--E   <-- master
           \
            F--G   <-- branch-a
```

Note how much this begins to resemble what you wish you had.  Let's stop drawing in the lower part of the graph, but remember it's still there, and now create `new-branch-a` and get on it:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch-a

A--D'-E'   <-- new-master, new-branch-a (HEAD)
```

and then cherry-pick `B`, `C`, `F`, and `G`:

```
$ git cherry-pick <hash of B>

A--D'-E'   <-- new-master
       \
        B'   <-- new-branch-a (HEAD)
```

(repeat for the remaining three commits):

```
A--D'-E'   <-- new-master
       \
        B'-C'-F'-G'   <-- new-branch-a (HEAD)
```

Now we go back to `new-master` and create `new-branch-b` and cherry-pick all of old `branch-b`'s commits:

```
        H'-I'   <-- new-branch-b (HEAD)
       /
A--D'-E'   <-- new-master
       \
        B'-C'-F'-G'   <-- new-branch-a
```

**All we have to do now is delete the original three branch names, and *rename* these three branches to `master`, `branch-a`, and `branch-b`, and anyone who doesn't remember the original *hash IDs* will think that history has somehow, magically, been rewritten.**  History really hasn't actually changed at all, and everyone with the original commits and the original names still has the original history—and this is where it gets kind of hairy, because Git is distributed.

***Everyone who has a clone of the repository has all the original commits with their original hash IDs.***  This means that every member of your team has, in their own Git repository, names of the form `origin/master`, `origin/branch-a`, and `origin/branch-b` that remember the hash IDs of commits `E`, `G`, and `I`, and they have all the original commits that are in the form you *don't* want—the original history, not the rewritten history.

They must carefully take any work *they* have that builds upon `E`, `G`, or `I`, and *transplant* that work (using `git cherry-pick` or equivalent) so that it now grows from `E'`, `G'`, or `I'`.  If your team is small enough, and everyone has been through the meeting to talk about how to deal with this history rewrite, though, that will probably be as easy for them as the rewrite was for you.

The tricky part is that if they're *not* careful, they can re-introduce all the original commits back into their own history (by having their branch names point to the originals, or to commits whose parents point back to the originals).  Then when they go to merge their history with your rewritten history, they re-introduce all the original history.  This sort of thing is why "history rewriting" is often a bad idea: it only takes one person getting it wrong to re-introduce the "wrong" history.

(The other thing that's a problem with history rewriting is merge commits.  You cannot cherry-pick a merge commit to create a new merge.  There are things you can do, but all choices have issues.  In your particular case, though, you have no merge commits yet, so you're safe here.)

#### Method two: revert

Instead of rewriting history, you can just add things to history.  This is safer in one sense: Git is built to add new commits atop old ones, so all of this happens naturally without any extra work on anyone else's part.  The drawback is that it's ugly, and when you go to `git merge` the other branches, each merge will require extra work.

Once again, the key to understanding this starts with drawing the graph (or at least some of it, and yours is small enough to just draw all of it):

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G   <-- branch-a
```

We now want to "undo" commits `C` and `B`, in that order, in both `branch-a` and `branch-b`.  The Git command that does this is `git revert`.  Revert, which probably should have been called "backout" instead, works much the same way is `git cherry-pick`.

This undoing may have conflicts (but if so, note that the history rewrite in Method One will have conflicts as well).  We'll start by reverting `C`, which compares `B` vs `C` to see what changed.  It then does *the opposite* of whatever changed, to where we are now.  Let's get on `branch-a`, i.e., commit `G`, and do a backing-out undoing of these changes from C:

```
$ git checkout branch-a
$ git revert <hash of C>
```

As with cherry-pick, revert will make a new commit if all goes well, with a commit message saying "this reverts ":

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G--J   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
```

(I don't have a clever way to write an upside down C or something ... well, I do, e.g., `Ↄ`, but I worry it might not show up well in some fonts/browsers.)  Now we must back out `B` as well, with a second `git revert` command:

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G--J--K   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
```

Now we repeat this work on `branch-b` by checking it out and reverting twice.  (As a small short-cut, we might notice that `git revert` can revert more than one commit: we can select both commits on the command line.  But the important thing is we revert both, in the correct order of back-to-front in case `C` depends on `B`.)  The result is now:

```
              H--I--L--M   <-- branch-b (HEAD)
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G--J--K   <-- branch-a
```

where all four of the new commits are backing-out reversions of `C` and then `B`.

We could also back out `C` and `B` on `master`, but that would be silly since we probably want to put them right back.  That would add four commits to `E` and the final source snapshot would match the snapshot in `E`.  It won't help any with future merges, either, as the point at which the two branches rejoin with the `master` branch remains commit `E`.

#### The trap that Method 2 sets up

The drawback to doing all this reverting occurs later, when you go to merge the branches back into `master`.  To understand the drawback, look back at the drawing we already have (or if you've erased it, draw it again :-) ).  Starting from the tips of `branch-a` and `master`, work backwards (leftwards) to the first commit you can get to that's on *both* branches.  That's commit `E`, so commit `E` is the merge base.

When we later run `git checkout master && git merge branch-a`, Git will look at the tip of `branch-a` and the tip of `master` and work backwards to find `E`.  No matter how many commits we add to `branch-a` and `master`, as long as we have not yet merged, we'll eventually come back to `E` here.

Git will, at this point, run two `git diff`s (in effect anyway):

```
git diff --find-renames E <tip of master>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames E <tip of branch-a> # what they changed
```

Whatever we've done in `master`, Git notes which files are affected (and which lines of those files).  Whatever they've done in `branch-a`, Git notes which files are affected (and which lines of those files).  Note that "we", in `master`, haven't done *anything* to *any* files that were affected by `B` and `C` yet.  Even if we revert and re-cherry-pick them, we still haven't done anything to them, because Git doesn't look at each individual commit, it just looks at the end product.

They, in `branch-a`, on the other hand ... well, they *reverted* stuff, so they have a backing-out of what was in `B` and `C` in *their* tip, as compared to commit `E`.  So Git thinks that it's important to back out what was in `B` and `C`.  Merging `branch-a` will therefore back out `B` and `C`, just as we are very clearly telling Git is important to do.

The trap, then, is that after merging `branch-a` we must remember to put these two commits back, e.g., by cherry-picking them.  Or, equivalently, just before merging `branch-a` we can put the two commits back into `branch-a` by cherry-picking them.  Now the second diff, to see what they did in `branch-a`, *won't* include backing out `B` and `C`.

This trap repeats with `branch-b`, which contains in *its* contents (as compared with commit `E`) a backing out of `B` and `C`.  **Note that we will very likely *not* get any conflict here; we *must* remember to re-add the commits at each merge.**  The lack of a conflict is the trap!

#### The hybrid: back out, merge, and cherry-pick

Now, as we saw above, the problem with avoiding history rewriting is that we set up traps for our later `git merge` commands.  But what if, instead, we violate some usual good-practice rules and do merges early?

Let's go back to our initial graph one more time:

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G   <-- branch-a
```

Suppose at this point we `git checkout master && git revert <C> && git revert <B>` to get this:

```
              H--I   <-- branch-b
             /
A--B--C--D--E--J--K   <-- master (HEAD)
             \
              F--G   <-- branch-a
```

The `master` branch tip commit `K` now looks like—that is, has as its source snapshot—what we wished `E` had looked like at the time we made the two side branches.  So now we can *merge* master *into* the two side branches.  This is sometimes a bad idea, but we'll do it a bit carefully:

```
$ git checkout branch-a && git merge master
# write a commit message explaining that this is a special backout merge
(and repeat for branch-b)
```

Now our graph looks like this:

```
              H--I--M   <-- branch-b (HEAD)
             /     /
A--B--C--D--E--J--K   <-- master
             \     \
              F--G--L   <-- branch-a
```

Now we immediately go back to `master` and bring `B` and `C` back by cherry-picking them (or reverting their reverts, which does the same thing).  Let's call the revert-of-revert or re-picks `B'` and `C'` since they resemble `B` and `C` a lot:

```
              H--I--M   <-- branch-b
             /     /
A--B--C--D--E--J--K--B'-C'  <-- master (HEAD)
             \     \
              F--G--L   <-- branch-a
```

Commit `L`, the merge at the tip of `branch-a`, now points back to `G` and `K` (in that order).  We won't worry about `branch-b` since it's basically the same.  Commit `L` has the effect of *undoing* `B` and `C`.

Let's imagine, now, we move forward in time and people make some commits on `branch-a`:

```
              H--I--M   <-- branch-b
             /     /
A--B--C--D--E--J--K--B'-C'  <-- master
             \     \
              F--G--L--N--O--P   <-- branch-a
```

It's now time to `git checkout master && git merge branch-a`.  What commit will `git merge` choose as the merge base?

Follow the links backwards to see which commits are on which branches.  `C'` is on `master` (only); `B'` is on master (only); `K` is on both branches.  Commits `P`, `O`, `N`, and `L` are on `branch-a` only, but `L` reaches back to `K`.  ***The merge base is now commit `K`.***

Git will now compare `K`'s content (which does not have the changes from `B` and `C`) to `C'`'s content: the change on master is to restore the two commits.  That's what *we* did.  Then Git will compare `K`'s content to `P`'s, to see what they did.  That will *not* include backing out `B` and `C` (since that's what `G` vs `L` does, so `K` vs `L` doesn't).  If we get any conflicts, they won't include the backing-out parts.  We can just do a normal merge, the way we'd do any other merge.  The final result is:

```
              H--I--M   <-- branch-b
             /     /
A--B--C--D--E--J--K--B'-C'-----Q  <-- master (HEAD)
             \     \          /
              F--G--L--N--O--P   <-- branch-a
```

where `Q` is built from `K` plus our changes (re-introduce `B` and `C`) plus their changes (introduce `F`+`G`+`N`+`O`+`P`).